# Merging Data From Two different Tables with the same fields

Tags: sql-server

Table1:

```
Acctno
-------
1
2
4
5
```

Table2:

```
Acctno
-------
1
3
4
6
```

Result:

```
Acctno
-------
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: What's the question? Do you want a union?

Comment: Please add few more words, it looks like union operation only..

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT Acctno FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT Acctno FROM Table2
ORDER BY Acctno
```

Result:

```
ACCTNO
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2520/1).